Unity Transform Instantiated weapon's world position is set to (0, 0, 0) despite specifying a different position
I'm working on a Unity project where I'm trying to instantiate a weapon at a specific position to fire bullets. I've set up a weaponPoint in the scene with the correct coordinates. However, when I instantiate the weapon, its world position is always (0, 0, 0), even though the weaponPoint and firePosition have been correctly set to right location.
I have set the weapon as a child object of the player's tank when it's instantiated, and the player's tank is not positioned at (0, 0, 0). If I manually drag the weapon into the player's script in the Unity editor, the bullets are instantiated correctly in front of the player without any issues
public class WeaponPickUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Weapon[] weapons;
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            other.GetComponent<PlayerTank>().SetWeapon(weapons[Random.Range(0,3)]);

            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}

public class PlayerTank : TankBase
{
    [SerializeField] private Weapon currentWeapon;
   public override void Fire()
   {
       currentWeapon?.Fire(this);
   }
    public void SetWeapon(Weapon weapon)
    {
        this.currentWeapon = weapon;
        Instantiate(weapon.gameObject, weaponPoint.position, weaponPoint.rotation, weaponPoint);

    }
   
}




public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Bullet bulletPrefab;

    [SerializeField] private Transform[] firePosition;

    public void Fire(TankBase shooterObj)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < firePosition.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(bulletPrefab.gameObject, firePosition[i].position, firePosition[i].rotation);
            Debug.Log("Weapon Position"+transform.position);
            Debug.Log(firePosition[i].position);
            Debug.Log("TestLocalPosition"+firePosition[i].localPosition);
           
        }
    }
}


I would like to know where I went wrong and what is causing this issue
Thank you in advance :)
The issue I had before, was it because our currentWeapon = weapon, but I never actually changed the position of this currentWeapon. It was still at the default prefab position. Even though I instantiated a new object below, the instantiated object wasn't related to our current currentWeapon,Is this right ? –
    public void SetWeapon(Weapon weapon)
{
    this.currentWeapon = weapon;
    currentWeapon = Instantiate(weapon, weaponPoint.position, weaponPoint.rotation, weaponPoint);

    

}


The weapon I added to the player's tank is using the position of the prefab instead of the player's position. I'm really confused about why this is happening.

Can you add an image to illustrate the positions of the PlayerTank, weapon, weaponPoint, and bullet?

Please include the code for SetFather

@shingo  I've solved the problem by changing the code like this. The issue I had before, was it because our currentWeapon = weapon, but I never actually changed the position of this object? It was still at the default prefab position. Even though I instantiated a new object below, the instantiated object wasn't related to our current currentWeapon

public void SetWeapon(Weapon weapon)
{
this.currentWeapon = weapon;
currentWeapon = Instantiate(weapon, weaponPoint.position, weaponPoint.rotation, weaponPoint);
}

What's likely causing the problem is in the instantiate call you have 'weaponPoint' being called for position, rotation, and parent transform. This isn't shown in the given code you have but it would be good to check what object transform is attached to the 'weaponPoint'. Likely is going to be (0,0,0).
If this isn't the problem then what might be occurring is the fact that the player tank is a prefab and the weapon point variable you've linked is found in position (0,0,0) for said prefab. The solution I've found for similar situations is grabbing the object you want to be used in the game scene (In this case the game object that you want to become 'weaponPoint') and having that be the object that's attached to the 'Player Tank'.
This is a quirk of the Unity prefabs system where they return the base prefabs position instead of the values of the object that you created based on the prefab. By giving the in-scene tank weapon point you are making sure it gets the correct version.
You can update it through the inspector of the Player Tank script by dragging the correct object to the 'weaponPoint' variable. Assuming you've exposed said variable. Or you can create a method in the level manager/game manager to send the correct object to the tank script when you spawn the Player Tank.
If neither of these options works you would need to provide more info on how you determine the weapon point and how the Player Tank is given that information as well as how the prefabs are set up for both the Player Tank and weapons.

thank you for the explanation,this helps me a lot
